# Large mesh cheesecloth? Straining pulp (not juice) from plums for jam

Tags: fruit, jam, jelly

Each year I have huge quantities of small cherry plums (roughly 2x cherry size).
The problem is the pits.  Is there a large mesh cheesecloth available I could try?

- I've tried cooking partially, then a food mill.  The pits get jammed under the wiper.
- I've tried a cherry pitter. Messy and slow.
- I've tried a paperclip to get the pits out.  Slow.
- I've tired of cutting the pits out.

Can I cook up the jam partially then run through a large mesh bag, to separate the pits?  Maybe a woven polyester?  What kind of mesh bag would be large enough to pass pulp, small enough to hold pits, strong enough to survive the twist and squeeze,and also food safe?

Answer (score 2):

I use nylon straining bags for making wine. You can get them in various sizes at homebrew stores. (for example: http://www.midwestsupplies.com/nylon-straining-bag-18-x-32-coarse-mesh.html) I'm sure they'd do the trick for what you need. Although this may only work for passing juice, you might inquire at your local homebrew store if they have a slightly larger mesh size.

Comment: Another thing I am thinking of is passing the pulp through a mesh strainer, one of those metal ones with slightly large openings. I don't know if you'll get a large enough mesh with cheesecloth or a straining bag for pulp, unless it's really runny.

Answer (score 0):

Nylon screen, from the hardware store, and butterfly netting, from the fabric store, have worked for me when I've dealt w similar separation problems. Both are reaonably cheap.